# How can I solve this error in my React Native projet?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm making my first app in React Native using Typescript and when I tried setting a navigation button in my app, using 'react-navigation' and 'react-native-screens', I got an error:

"No overload matches this call.
Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."

Why? And how can I fiz this? I'm using functional components, not class.
The TouchableOpacity has an onPress property which triggers a function that triggers the navigation adn sends the user to another page. Eventho the error is theere, the code works fine. I'm just trying to understand the 'whys' and 'hows' behind this. I'm a Jr with less than a year of experience.

export default function Welcome() {
const navigation = useNavigation();

return (

```
  <View style={styles.containerLogo}>
    <Animatable.Image
      animation='flipInY'
      source={require('../../assets/logoPackage.png')}
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
      resizeMode='contain'
    />
    <Text style={styles.logoName}>I See It</Text>
  </View>

  <Animatable.View delay={600} animation='fadeInUp' style={styles.containerForm}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Bem vindo!</Text>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Faça o login para começar a rastrear seus items!</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('SignIn')}
     >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </Animatable.View>
</View>
```

)
}

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but I think it's all about this line:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Navigation works because 'SignIn' scene really exists, but useNavigation doesn't know what scene names it can use and expects explicit parameters. Welcome to Typescript.

Try to use this:

```
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
...
const { navigate } = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<yourNavigationTypeParams>>();
```